# Dynamics CRM hierarchy security

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

We have Dynamics 365 online V9.

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/hierarchy-security

- User 1 is a direct manager of User 2.
- I (other user) share a record with User 2, giving him read, write, and all other rights to the record.

After sharing the record, I connect to CRM with the User 1 credentials: the result is that I can read the record that was previously shared, but I don't have any other rights (write, share, etc.). Is this normal, or is it a product bug?

EDIT: thanks to Arun Vinoth, my conclusion is that one sentence in the article that I reported should be modified in this way:

Current: "User 1, as a direct manager of User 2, has access to the accounts owned by or shared with User 2"

Proposed correction: "User 1, as a direct manager of User 2, has FULL access to the accounts owned by User 2, and only READ access to the accounts shared with User 2".

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says:

> For a non-direct report, a manager has the Read-only access to the report’s data. For a direct report, the manager has the Read, Write, Update, Append, AppendTo access to the report’s data.

So in your case User1 (Manager) will get Read/Write access but not Share access, provided his (or his Team) Security Role giving him privilege to Read/Edit.

> With the Manager hierarchy security model, a manager has access to the records owned by the user or by the team that a user is a member of, and to the records that are directly shared with the user or the team that a user is a member of.
>
> In addition to the Manager hierarchy security model, a manager must have at least the user level Read privilege on an entity, to see the reports’ data. For example, if a manager doesn’t have the Read access to the Case entity, the manager won’t be able to see the cases that their reports have access to.

Comment: You talk about Security Role, but I think that this aspect is independent from the fact that User 1 should have the same rights on the record that User 2 has, in fact User 2 has rights on the record not because of Security Roles, but because the record was shared with him. @Arun Vinoth.

Comment: @Sean Role based security is first gatepass, then only object based security (sharing) will take effect. Hierarchy is next granular level access.

Comment: Do you see Read-only yellow bar on the bottom of the form?

Comment: @Sean is that record owned by user/team in different BU? User1 has user level or BU level instead of org level Write privilege?

Comment: I think that you are right: the record is owned by a user in a different BU, and the  security level is "Parent BU and sub BUs". If I set the security level to "Organisation", User 1 has all the rights on the record. So, only READ access is passed to the manager, even when a record is shared with all the rights to his direct report?  @Arun Vinoth

Comment: @Sean any lower level security model cannot breach higher level :)

Comment: But it does breach, since User 1 could read the record, before changing the security role! And read was not included in the security role. @Arun Vinoth

Comment: Please can you read my EDIT in the answer, and tell me if you agree?  @Arun Vinoth

Comment: @Sean your proposed correction may be true for one case: your scenario. It may cover few more scenario. But the doc is for general use case. If you share the record with same BU, current doc is right.

Comment: If I set the Security Role with Organisation permissions (read/write/share etc) on the entity, then User 1, that has this Security Role, will be able to do anything with the record, independently from the share, no? What I don't understand is that when you share a record, you have to define the rights (read/write etc.), so why the manager takes only the READ rights, if the  record was shared with all the  rights to his report?  @Arun Vinoth

Comment: @Sean good question, you can share the feedback in that doc link in bottom using github. Let MS clear the doubt.